# Core Animation Callbacks

Tags: cocoa, macos, delegates, core-animation, callback

I'm using core animation to transition between different view states in my application. However, I need to find a way to perform different tasks after the animations finish. I understand I can implement a delegate method and use the

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag;
```

callback, however there's no easy way of keeping track of which animation is ending.

I can think of some tedious solutions, like using a series of flags and counters, however I'm wondering if there is a more efficient and practical method to getting around this problem.

What are some thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `setValue:ForKey` method to assign a unique name to each animation.

```
[animation setValue:@"myUniqueName" forKey:@"name"];
```

Later, in the animationDidStop method use that to find out which animation stopped

```
-(void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)finished {
    if([[theAnimation valueForKey:@"name"] isEqual: @"myUniqueName"] && finished){
               //code
    } 
    if([[theAnimation valueForKey:@"name"] isEqual: @"otherName"] && finished){
        //code
    } 
}
```